# What is best way to add functionaly (like wordpress plugin) to laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel development, i want to know that is there way to create a plugin for laravel and then install. Install process should be very easy like just copy paste one folder to laravel or run the command. Can anyone guide me I would like to appreciate.

Comment: The install process could be via composer. Take a look to [this](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you install "plugins" as packages. You just have to look for a package you want to use.

http://packalyst.com/

Then you just add it to your composer.json and the package is installed. Normally in these packages you will find the instructions to configure them:

- Normally, you have to add a new provider and a facade to be used all along your code.
- Usually you have to publish vendors if the package need them.

In GitHub also you will find for each project the instructions to be installed. For example, for a great DebugBar for your project (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) the instructions will be:

1. Install vendor code: composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
2. Add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php
3. Publish vendors: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what i wanted to know. Is there any good tutorial for beginner? I appreciate you.

Comment: I think the best way to learn is just try to install one like this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar It's very easy.

Comment: What about server ? Means how to install the package on server ? Can you kindly guide me

Comment: Should be the same... If you have a GIT project, when you update on the server, you update the config files and the composer.lock that contains the packages you want to install. So just do "composer install" in your server should do the job.